TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
Код выглядит следующим образом:
import random

array1 = [random.randint(-25,25) for _ in range(4)]

print(f'Сгенерированный массив: {'{:>4d}'.format(array1),end=''}')

При этом в терминале выводится ошибка, что "end" не определено.
Окей, убираю:
import random

array1 = [random.randint(-25,25) for _ in range(4)]

print(f'Сгенерированный массив: {'{:>4d}'.format(array1)}')

В рабочей области ошибок нет, однако при выводе происходит ошибка "unsupported format string passed to list.format"
Какие изменения необходимо внести в код, чтобы вывести массив без скобок так, как это задумано? (метод join использовать нельзя)

print('Сгенерированный массив:', *[f'{num:>4d}' for num in array1], sep='')

Так какой формат вывода вы хотели получить на выходе то? Приведите пример прямо в вопросе.

Нужно каждый элемент списка форматировать, а вы в форматную строку для числа пытаетесь пропихнуть целый список.

Вот так будет без скобок
import random

array1 = [random.randint(-25,25) for _ in range(4)]

print('Сгенерированный массив:', *array1)

